# How to create scatterplot of age vs. bone density in two different colors depending on M or F

Tags: r

Trying to generate a scatterplot of some bone density data with age on the X axis and density on the Y axis. Only thing is I want the female data to be plotted in red and the male data to be plotted in blue.

```
bone <- read.csv('/Users/myname/Desktop/ML/spnbmd.csv')
plot(spnbmd ~ age, data=bone, col = 
       ifelse(sex=="fem", "red", "red2"), 
      xlab="Age", ylab="Relative Change in Spinal BMD")
```

That's where I'm at so far.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems reasonable - what is your issue with this approach? Perhaps your colors are just too similar to see the difference? If you provided a reproducible example people might be able to actually help you.

Here is a reproducible toy example:

```r
data("mtcars")
  plot(mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars, col = ifelse(am==0, "red", "blue"), 
       xlab="Age", ylab="Relative Change in Spinal BMD")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Ok I think I've got it now... as far as the if else statement that determines which color is assigned to which gender... does it assign the first color to the gender listed (fem in my example) and then the second color to the 'else' or vice versa

Comment: @Kyle - test it, and you'll see - `cbind(bone["sex"], col=ifelse(bone$sex=="fem", "red", "red2"))`

Answer (score 1):

or alternatively you can by using "ggplot2"

```
 gender <- c("M","F","M","M","F","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F")
 BMD <- c(10,15,20,25,30,20,80,45,65,20,3,45,23,66,25,14,17)
 age <- c(50,60,70,90,25,30,35,40,45,50,25,13,70,60,35,68,45)

 df <- data.frame(gender = as.factor(gender),BMD,age)

 **df %>% ggplot(aes(x = age, y = BMD,fill = gender))+geom_point(aes(color = gender),size = 4)`**
```